# MeteorJS login button change UI

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, frontend

I have ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 installed. I want a sign-in / sign-up **button** in the center of my home page.

Right now, {{> loginButtons}} gives the "Sign in / Sign up" dropdown, but it's a hyperlink. **How do I make the link a button?**

Embedding it in html tags doesn't work:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info"> {{> loginButtons}} </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was to remove the ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 and use instead the default accounts-ui.

Then I add the following in my js files (on the client)

Template.loginButtons.rendered = function(){
  Accounts._loginButtonsSession.set('dropdownVisible', true);
};

This should show all buttons and inputs without weird dropdowns. I would then style it by replicating bootstrap styles if needed.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what I'm gonna have to do